# Is it natural to say “I’d like a...” when ordering from a restaurant?

Tags: idiomatic-language

If ordering from a restaurant over the phone are the phrases written in bold completely natural in the context?

Me:             "Hi, **I'd like to order a** cheese burger..."

Restaurant guy: "A cheese burger..."

Me:             "**And then I'd like a** large Pepsi."

Restaurant guy: "And a large Pepsi. Would that be all?"

Me:             "Yes, that's all. **And I'd like it delivered to**...(address)."

Comment: Sounds completely normal to me. Many people would just say "I have an order for delivery" and let "Restaurant Guy" ask the relevant questions (What do you want, is that all, where to deliver).

Comment: I would say that *I'd like …* is very common and the equivalent to *I'll have …*, which is also very common.

Answer (score 1):

The bolded phrases sound natural to me (Native speaker of Australian English) with one exception:

The word "*then*" in the second phrase is a bit odd since it implies some sort of sequence which I don't think you mean.  When I read it as it is written it seems to be saying that you only want to receive the Pepsi after the cheese burger - but that would be pretty weird for an order that you want delivered.  Normally you would want all of your order together for a delivery.  (that might be different if you were sitting in the restaurant and were ordering mains and desserts though)

A slight improvement (without a total re-write) would be to say:

Me: "Hi, **I'd like to order a** cheese burger..."

Restaurant guy: "A cheese burger..."

Me: "**And I'd like a** large Pepsi."

Restaurant guy: "And a large Pepsi. Would that be all?"

Me: "Yes, that's all. **And I'd like it delivered to**...(address)."

Comment: Native American English speaker here, and "then" still seems perfectly natural. You're moving on to the next item on a list.